# Getting CPU usage of a specific process using APPLESCRIPT

Tags: applescript

I'm really new with applescript and it would definitely be a great help if you can advise me with my problem.

I am currently trying to create a script using the script editor that could check if the current CPU usage of Google Chrome exceeds 50%. However, i'm not sure if the returned value for the test is in integer form or string form. I'm having a problem in comparing the "test" with a specific number. Can you please help check what i'm not getting right? Thank you. Here is my current complete applescript that runs indefinitely until the Google Chrome CPU usage reaches 50% (Main issue here is i'm not sure with the comparison test < "50.0"):

```
getProcessPercentCPU("Google Chrome")

on getProcessPercentCPU(someProcess)
    set test to do shell script "/bin/ps -xco %cpu,command | /usr/bin/awk '/" & someProcess & "$/ {print $1}'"
    
    repeat while test < "50.0"
        set test to do shell script "/bin/ps -xco %cpu,command | /usr/bin/awk '/" & someProcess & "$/ {print $1}'"
    end repeat
    
    display dialog test
    
    
    
end getProcessPercentCPU
```

This script will supposedly display a dialog box if the "test" will reach 50.0 or more. However, the returned value in the dialog box is not accurate or not 50 or more. Please help.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use the *fully qualified pathname* of the *executable* in this use case as both `ps` and `awk` are within the `PATH` passed to the `do shell script`  *command*, i.e.: `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Also, you do not need to execute the `do shell script` *command* twice. Just set the *value* of `test` prior to the `repeat` *loop*, and use `as integer` on the result of the `do shell script` *command* e.g.:

```applescript
getProcessPercentCPU("Google Chrome")

on getProcessPercentCPU(someProcess)
    
    set test to 0
    
    repeat while test < 50
        set test to ¬
            (do shell script "ps -xco %cpu,command | awk '/" & someProcess & "$/ {print $1}'") ¬
                as integer
    end repeat
    
    display dialog test
    
end getProcessPercentCPU
```

---

That said, using a *loop* like this can become resource intensive, so you might consider adding a `delay` *command* inside of the *loop* so the `do shell script` *command* isn't triggered constantly one iteration directly after the other. Additionally, consider using some *method* to escape the *loop* after a given period of time.

With a `delay` and *timeout* added:

```
getProcessPercentCPU("Google Chrome")

on getProcessPercentCPU(someProcess)
    
    set i to 0
    set test to 0
    
    repeat while test < 50
        set test to ¬
            (do shell script "ps -xco %cpu,command | awk '/" & someProcess & "$/ {print $1}'") ¬
                as integer
        delay 2
        set i to i + 1
        if i ≥ 10 then exit repeat      
    end repeat
    
    display dialog test
    
end getProcessPercentCPU
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'll try your recommendations. I'm really new to the scripting world so I'm trying to fully understand everything bit by bit. Thaanks!